# How can I unit test this hitTest override in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, hittest, ocmock

How can I unit test this `hitTest` override?

```
- (UIView*) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    // Do something based on hitView's properties
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `UIEvent` does not have a public constructor, and thus I can't create an `UIEvent` to produce different results on `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]`.

Alternatively I could create a mock `UIEvent`, but that would imply knowing what `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]` does with it, which I don't, and even if I did, it might change.

Another option would be to swizzle `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]` (with [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/)) but I don't know if it's possible to swizzle just the superclass implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the call to super and use a partial mock.

In the class under test, create something like:

```
-(UIView *)checkHit:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Then in your test class:

```
CGPoint testPoint = CGPointMake(1,2);
id mockHitView = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIView class]];
id mockSomething = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:realObject];
[[[mockSomething stub] andReturn:mockHitView] checkHit:testPoint withEvent:[OCMArg any]];

[realObject hitTest:testPoint withEvent:nil];
```

Comment: +1 While this would work, it forces me to create a method that makes the code slightly more confusing. I'm not against adding code for testing purposes as long as it makes the code clearer (fortunately, it usually does).